# Getting value from response.body in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, http

My response.body from a HTTP `get` looks like this:

```
{"Code":1,"Message":"Successfully retrieved subscriberId","Result":22687813}
```

How can I declare the value of "Result" as a variable?

**SOLVED**
This was a result of my lack of Ruby-skills and JSON experience, solved by doing "JSON.parse response.body" before puts response.body["Message"].

Comment: try `response.body['Result']`

Comment: Thank you, but that only seems to set the variable to "Message"?

Comment: you mean you get "Successfully retrieved subscriberId" when you try response.body['Result']? that's weird.

Comment: No, that is what i would like to get, but i only get 'Response' (Sorry, typed wrong answer in prev. comment)

Comment: sorry i really don't get what you mean.  what's returned by `response.body['Result']`?

Comment: Only the text Result. 

puts response.body['Result'] retursn Result

Comment: That sounds very strange. What is the class of response.body? I.e. `puts response.body.class.name`.

Comment: also try puts response.body.inspect to make sure that you are working on the expected format of response.body

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, solved it by adding JSON.parse..